# Get 500.0 Internal Server Error on Post request after publishing Azure web application

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure web API service hosting our different functional APIs. The problem I am having right now is when I send a POST request, it returns 500 with response body

{
"error": "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."
}
but the request goes through (The functionality works fine). By using Log stream on the Azure portal, I can see the following details:

```
<body>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="content-container">
                <h3>HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error</h3>
                <h4>The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="content-container">
                <fieldset>
                    <h4>Most likely causes:</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker
                            process when this error occurred.
                        </li>
                        <li>IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.</li>
                        <li>IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.</li>
                        <li>The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.</li>
                        <li>The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.</li>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="content-container">
                <fieldset>
                    <h4>Things you can try:</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.</li>
                        <li>Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.</li>
                        <li>Verify the permissions for the DLL.</li>
                        <li>Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.</li>
                        <li>
                            Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click
                            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </div>

            <div class="content-container">
                <fieldset>
                    <h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4>
                    <div id="details-left">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr class="alt">
                                <th>Module</th>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AspNetCoreModuleV2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Notification</th>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="alt">
                                <th>Handler</th>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;aspNetCore</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Error Code</th>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000000</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div id="details-right">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr class="alt">
                                <th>Requested URL</th>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;https://SFSPolicyControllerDev__73a0:80/api/policyRequests?clientId=sfspmnode</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Physical Path</th>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D:\home\site\wwwroot\api\policyRequests</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="alt">
                                <th>Logon Method</th>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Logon User</th>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="content-container">
                <fieldset>
                    <h4>More Information:</h4>
                    This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.
                    <p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=500,0,0x00000000,14393">View more information &raquo;</a></p>
                    <p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

The framework I use is shown below.

[image]

I tried some solutions from online, e.g. checked the storage account and database's firewall settings to make sure it checked the checkbox to enable other services access it, added database and storage account key value pairs to app settings on the portal, update WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION from 6.9.1 to 8.9.4, but none of them seemed to work. I feel this could be because of the configuration setting but I have no idea why and how to fix it. Please let me know if I need to provide more details. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have deployed ASP.NET Core Web API and able to access the post request, follow the below steps

- Create an ASP.NET Core API in Visual studio
- Below is the file structure

[image]

**ProductsController.cs**

- Use post method in `ProductController.cs` use the below

```cs
[HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
        public ActionResult<Product> Add(ProdDto prodDto)
        {
            var prod = prodDto.ToProduct();
            _prodService.Add(prod);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = prod.Id }, prod);
        }
```

- Deployed the Web-app to Azure app service from visual studio
  [image]
- If you want to access the API from anywhere with the URL follow as below

[image]

- Mark it as **Yes**

[image]

- Follow the below to pass the values

```
{  
"id": "GUID",  
"name": "TAB",  
"price": 100  
}
```

- I have tried the post request and got the below output

[image]